# Why is the integral $C^\infty$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Differentiable manifolds from Warner.

In order to prove that the dimension of the tangent space is the same as the dimension of the manifold, they use the following calculus lemma -

If $g$ is of class $C^k$ ($k \geq 2$) on a convex open subset $U$ about $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then for each $q \in U$,
$g(q)\ =\ g(p) + \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial g}{\partial r_i}|_p (r_i(q)-r_i(p))+\sum_{i,j}(r_i(q)-r_i(p))(r_j(q)-r_j(p))\int_0^1(1-t)\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}|_{(p+t(q-p))} dt.$

This is the Taylor expansion. It further says, if $g\in C^\infty$, then the integral as a function of $q$ is of class $C^\infty$. How is this? Do we have to use fundamental theorem of calculus or something like that?

Comment: Read the condition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). You can show by induction that the integral is of the class $C^k$ for any $k\in \Bbb N$

Comment: I am still not clear. Are we to consider the integrand as a function of $q$ and $t$? If so how is the partial derivative of the integrand with respect to q continuous, i.e. how do we say that?

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\int_0^1(1-t)\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}|_{(p+t(q-p))} dt$ can be differentiated under the integral sign to obtain all of its partial derivatives.  Since $g$ is $C^\infty$, so is the integral.

Comment: That's not true right? $g(q)-g(p) - \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial g}{\partial r_i}|_p (r_i(q)-r_i(p)) = \sum_{i,j}(r_i(q)-r_i(p))(r_j(q)-r_j(p))\int_0^1(1-t)\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial r_i\partial r_j}|_{(p+t(q-p))} dt$. So can we still conclude the integral is $C^\infty$?

Comment: Sorry, I was just relying on your formula too quickly, which I misread slightly.  Divide by the expression $\sum_{i,j}(r_i(q)-r_i(p))(r_j(q)-r_j(p))$ to get a formula for the integral in terms of $g(q)$ and its first partials at $p$, and the same argument applies.  You don't even need differentiability of the partials since you are only using them at a single point $p$.

Comment: How can I do that? The summation runs over the integral too, there are terms in the integrand which depend on $i, j$.

Comment: Right.  I really answered this in too much of a hurry. Then you should be asking about "the integrals as a function of q" (in the plural) rather than "the integral as a function of q"?

Comment: Yes that's right. Integrals as functions of q.